# How to use a branch for a yeoman generator

Tags: javascript, git, github, yeoman

I have a yeoman generator installed globally on my system. I would like to use the "canary" branch of a yeoman project if I type `$ yo` into the console. Currently it uses the master branch.

Anyone any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install your generator globally from `npm` like this

```
npm install -g grunt-usemin
```

it takes the latest released (published) version from a registry.

If you would like to install a specific version from any branch, you can specify link to that repository, for example, for `appveyor` branch, add `@appveyor` at the end:

```
npm install -g https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin.git@appveyor
```

Here is full npm syntax reference: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: Current version of npm, `3.5.1`, uses a `#` instead of `@`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install a branch version of a generator from a GitHub repository, you will need to suffix the URI with `#<branch_name>` as per the installation of any git hosted `npm` package.

The command to install a branch named `canary` for a yeoman generator in a repository named `my-yeoman-generator` hosted on GitHub will look like this:

`$ npm install -g https://github.com/username/my-yeoman-generator.git#canary`